# Long MySQL blocks server

Tags: php, mysql

I might have a basic design problem and I think I need some advice to solve this. My PHP script calls Mysqli functions to retrieve the info from the DB. If the Query is long, the server becomes irresponsive until the query has finished. This has many negative implications because I have dozens of users connected at the same time and it ruins their experience.

Is this behaviour normal (server locked while long MySQL queries)? Can it be solved? What would be the next steps? Is there any workaround?

To be clear, what I need is other users to be able to use the site normally while other users may be waiting for a long query to finish.

```
$querystring =  "***long query***";
$process = mysqli_query($con, $querystring );
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($process);
```

Then later a while loop going through the results.

I have to say that the MySQL query surely can be improved, but sometimes I will find situations where the queries are already optimized.

My server is running Apache + Nginx and PHP-FPM

Any tips or guidance? Thanks

Comment: close a session

Comment: Use a cache...?

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Session is closed once the mysqli operations are finalised with mysqli_close().

Comment: I don't see how a cache would sort the problem @tyteen4a03

Comment: mysqli has nothing to do with php sessions.

Comment: Then you only have to run the expensive query once.

Comment: I think we´re missing the point here. My question is more about the capability of the technologies, can we run several long queries at the same time without the server becoming irresponsive?